# I am trying to create a listview screen, but there is an error in the 'myChildren' part. What could be the cause?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a listview screen, but there is an error in the 'myChildren' part.
What could be the cause?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etBiq.jpg)

Comment: replace `myChildren` to `widget.myChildren` in build function

Comment: You need to declare "myChilden" in _MyHomePageState, not in MyHomePage widget

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Either move `myChildren` to `_MyHomePageState` class or replace `myChildren` with `widget.myChildren` in `build` method.

Also everytime when `build` method calls you add 50 text widgets to `myChildren`. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> myChildren = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      for(var i = 0; i<50;i++){
        myChildren.add(const Text('Hellow World'));
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: myChildren.isEmpty
          ? const SizedBox()
          : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: myChildren.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return myChildren[index];
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```